# Dynamically starting DB thread pool in Play

Tags: playframework, datasource, threadpool, playframework-2.3

I have multiple databases defined in the `conf/application.conf` file like this:

```
db.something.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.something.url="jdbc:mysql://host:3306/something"
db.something.user=user
db.something.pass=pass
```

On startup, a thread pool / datasource is setup by Play for each schema. How can I do this programmatically? I have to be able to add datasources dynamically while the application is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging through the Play source code I found this method in `play.db.Databases`:

```
    public static Database createFrom(String name, String driver, String url, Map<String, ? extends Object> config) {
        ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object> dbConfig = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>();
        dbConfig.put("driver", driver);
        dbConfig.put("url", url);
        dbConfig.putAll(config);
        return new DefaultDatabase(name, dbConfig.build());
    }
```

Use it by calling: `Databases.createFrom("mydb", "driver", "url", conf)` with the last param containing username and password and whatever else you need.

The database definitions in `application.conf` are then obsolete. However it makes sense to store these Database objects in a Map for later reuse.